How to select data all tables mysql
How can I search for data in every table in the database?
For example, searching for the word ca from the name column of every table in the database.
database name : record
Table 1:



country
name




Jordan
Jessica


Singapore
Belinda



Table 2:



country
name




Fiji
Veronica


Australia
Katherine



Will show information

Jessica : Jordan

Veronica : Fiji


I'm trying to use
 SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_NAME, ';') INTO @sql 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'   
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'record' 
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;  
      
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
 EXECUTE stmt; 
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

But it didn't work.

Technically you would need a GROUP_CONCAT with UNION ALL as the separator, however the real problem is your tables aren't structured (in one table) like the way you use it.

See JayRizzo's answer to the duplicate question.

Answer:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ABsXQV4E
